# Filter running recursively

Tags: servlets, servlet-filters

I have written a servlet filter and It is running recursively.

I want to take control to the login page when in the session a particular attribute is not set.

Actually login page is having same url-pattern as other pages

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>AppFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>web.AppFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>AppFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</filter>
```

Kindly tell me a solution where doFilter should not run recursively.

Answer (score 0):

Just check in the filter if the request URI matches the login page itself so that it won't be redirected.

```
String loginURI = request.getContextPath() + "/faces/login.xhtml";

if (user != null || request.getRequestURI().equals(loginURI)) {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
else {
    response.sendRedirect(loginURI);
}
```